# overriding char arrays with struct

Tags: c

I'm working with structures in C for the first time and I hate to admit that I don't think I'm understanding it very well. I'm trying to build an array of pointers that point to Student structures to create a whole database of students. The problem is that if I create more then one student, the first students name and courses get overridden by the second students. Also, the output on name only is really weird. If I give the name "Sarah" I get back "Sara?  LG??fa?e" But the courses come out fine. I feel like I might be doing something wrong with the memory allocation? We've just leaned about that too, and I don't understand it 100% either.

Here's the part of code I'm working on right now:

```
typedef struct student Student;

struct student 
{
    char *name;
    int age;
    char *course1;
    char *course2;
};

Student *Data[30];
int count = 0;

void new()
{
    int age;
    char name [300];
    char course1 [300];
    char course2 [300];
    char together[300];
    char remarks[300];

    printf("name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);

    printf("age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    printf("course-1: ");
    scanf("%s", course1);

    printf("course-2: ");   
    scanf("%s", course2);

    Data[count] = malloc(sizeof(Student));
    Data[count]->name = name;
    Data[count]->age = age;
    Data[count]->course1 = course1;
    Data[count]->course2 = course2;
    count++;

}

void display()
{

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        printf("name:\t%s\n", Data[i]->name);
        printf("age:\t%d\n", Data[i]->age);
        printf("course1:\t%s\n", Data[i]->course1);
        printf("course2:\t%s\n", Data[i]->course2);
    }


}
```

Thanks for your help everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

Oh, you are not allocating memory anywhere for individual `Student`. If the size of fields is known, you can declare storage as part of the structure:

```
struct student 
{
   char name[300];
   int age;
   char course1[300];
   char course2[300];
};
```

And then populate it as follows:

```
Data[count] = malloc(sizeof(Student));
strncpy(Data[count]->name, name, sizeof(Data[count]->name));
Data[count]->age = age;
strncpy(Data[count]->course1, course1, sizeof(Data[count]->course1));
strncpy(Data[count]->course2, course2, sizeof(Data[count]->course2));
```

If you want to use dynamic memory allocation, then the struct shall be as it is now, but the allocation changes:

```
Data[count] = malloc(sizeof(Student));
Data[count]->name = strdup(name);
Data[count]->age = age;
Data[count]->course1 = strdup(course1);
Data[count]->course2 = strdup(course2);

....
```

And when you deallocate, don't forget fields:

```
free(Data[count]->name);
free(Data[count]->course1);
free(Data[count]->course2);
free(Data[count]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are just copying references (pointers) to data, which means that your old data get lost. You need to make copies

```
Data[count]->name = (char*)malloc(...);
strcpy(Data[count]->name,name);
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

That is... not the normal way to handle pointers in a structure. You're setting pointers in the structure to local statically allocated arrays. What you want to do is `malloc()` memory for each of your array's structure members, ex:

```
void new()
{

    printf("name: ");
    Data[count]->name = malloc(300);
    scanf("%299s", Data[count]->name);
```

But when you're done with your code you now have to free the memory for all of your structures' elements as well as the structures themselves.

---

Now if you want to get a little fancier, *and* you're going to compile only with `gcc` you can use the `%a` or `%m` modifier (depending on the standard) to skip the mallocs:

```
    printf("name: ");
    scanf("%m", Data[count]->name);
```

But of course you have to free it yourself still.